# Relative size(height / width) of UIView relative to its superview in VFL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout, autolayout, visual-format-language

Is there way to set relative size(height / width) of UIView relative to its superview in VFL constraints?

I have following constraint and I would like to make infoView centered in scrollView with 75% size. My current constraints makes it of same size.

```
[self.farmScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[lastView]-10-[infoView(==_scrollView)]"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:@{@"lastView":lastView, @"infoView":infoView, @"_scrollView":_scrollView}]];
```

Comment: You mean, same **aspect ratio** as its superview?

Answer (score 0):

VLF has some limitations to the current implementation; a couple of the more notable are important to understand:

- Centering of views
- Using the multiplier component of constraints

Since the VFL creates multiple constraints and returns only an array of un-named constraints, the multiplier cannot be set through the format string.

Note: You could loop through each of the constraints returned by the constraintsWithVisualFormat method, but you would have to process each of them in turn to determine the NSLayoutAttribute so that you could correctly set your multiplier. But even then, you still have to replace that constraint because the multiplier isn't mutable.

From [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial)